# How to create a browser window with no buttons or toolbars that launches from desktop?

Tags: browser

I have a couple websites with math games for my kids that I want them to be able to use, but I do not want my kids to be able to navigate away from those sites.

Can I create a link/shortcut on the desktop of their computer that will open a browser window to the specified webpage, but will have no address bar and no buttons so they can not click away from the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the phrase *kiosk mode*.

For Windows, do this:

`C:\Users\jsherk\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -kiosk http://www.example.com/`

or this:

`'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe' -kiosk http://www.example.com/`

Note that to close the window, ALT+F4 is sufficient, so it's not inescapable.

Source: https://www.think2loud.com/868-google-chrome-full-screen-kiosk-mode/

EDIT:

For Mac you need to do this:

`open '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/' --args -kiosk http://example.com`

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. I have edited and added the MAC version to your answer as well.